# how to enable an external couchdb for hyerledger fabric

Tags: docker, couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am following the official docs of hyperledger-fabric, paticularly the part https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/couchdb_tutorial.html. I am just using the "test-network" demo.However, I've encountered some problems when I try to use couchdb:

1.How should I config my core.yaml to switch from leveldb to couchdb, and should I config each core.yaml of each peer?

2.Is the couchdb on the chaincode or in the docker container and can I use my local database to store the state data?

Any answer will be hugely appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Configure each peer's core.yaml to point to the respective peer's CouchDB. See the [CouchDB configuration documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/couchdb_as_state_database.html#couchdb-configuration) for details.
2. You will need a separate CouchDB for each peer. Typically the CouchDB is deployed to a separate container but 'close' to the peer container, e.g. in the same Kubernetes pod.